# How to group duplicate values into separate groups?

Tags: mysql, sql

Data

[image]

Needed Result

[image]

Now I have to query how to get count (id) and group by the single field. This means that when I get the result, it will be as shown in image 2. When I use this query, it will only correct the first when line, and the next when it will return the missing value due to the above condition. Hope you can help. Thanks.

```
select count(id)
from table
GROUP BY (CASE
WHEN `fields` like '%-31-%' THEN '31'
WHEN `fields` like '%-35-%' THEN '35'
WHEN `fields` like '%-49-%' THEN '49'
ELSE '52' END)
```

Comment: Each record will be examined for GROUP BY expression only once.

Comment: Well, you did set yourself up for failure with this data structure! Rather than trying to write a convoluted query to get the desired results from this structure, I would normalise your data first, then write a simple query with count and group by.

Comment: @Akina: So which function should I use to get the result?

Comment: @Shadow Thanks for your comment. This's not my database, but I have to retrieve data from this.

Comment: Do you always have 3 values in the fields field? Is the list of values within fields field fixed? If the answer to both questions is no, then you are really in a hot water and you won't be able to do what you want with a single query. If the answer to any of the questions is yes, then it is doable, but it will be convoluted, terribly resource intensive and slow.

Comment: @Shadow: Q1: No, it ranges 1-3 values. Q2: Yes, it's fixed, from 10 to 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select patterns.groupnum, count(table.id)
from table, ( SELECT '%-31-%' pattern, 31 groupnum UNION ALL
              SELECT '%-35-%'        , 35          UNION ALL
              SELECT '%-49-%'        , 49          UNION ALL
              SELECT '%-52-%'        , 52 ) patterns
WHERE table.`field` LIKE patterns.pattern
GROUP BY patterns.groupnum;
```

---

But I'd recommend you to normalize your data.

Comment: This solution only works if the list of possible values within fields field is fixed. Well, any of the solutions using selects have to assume that either the ist of values or the number of values within fields field is fixed.

Comment: @Shadow Of course the best way is to provide the criteria array as a temporary table - in addition to data normalization. Or the array may be provided in some form applicable for converting to the rowset - for example, as JSON array, which then will be parsed usng JSON_TABLE().

Comment: But you need to get the list from the fields field, which in itself is a challenge. Unless there is a separate table the OP did not mention.